# geoJSON for federally recognized tribal lands (US specifically)

Tags: geospatial

I need to represent all federally recognized native land on a map of the western US. I have found the geoJSON file from native-land.ca, and as much as I would love to use this representation, the requirements I am given requests differently. Does anyone know where to find such a file?

Alternatively, does anyone know where I could find a list of all COUNTIES in the US that have federally recognized tribal land?

I am relatively inexperienced with coding maps, and I'm hoping to find a JSON that I can import into my data visualization code.

Comment: You might be able to get a geojson from here: https://tigerweb.geo.census.gov/arcgis/rest/services/TIGERweb/TribalTracts/MapServer

I know the Census Bureau has probably as complete a record of federally-recognized tribal lands as you're likely to get, and it looks this gives you the option to get it in geojson if you query for it.

Comment: Thanks. It does look like there's a way to get that data. Sadly I don't know how to work the renderer to get the information I need. (I also don't have access to ArcGIS which would obviously work even better).